# JSF FlowFaces Unable to find matching navigation case from view ID 'CURRENT_PAGE' for outcome '<FLOW_NAME>'

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish, faces-flow

I have created a JSF Flow. My definition is as follows:

```
<flow-definition id="registration">
    <initializer>#{registrationBean.initializeFlow}</initializer>

    <start-node>personalDetails</start-node>

    <view id="personalDetails">
        <vdl-document>/registration/personal-details.xhtml</vdl-document>
    </view>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>registration</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/registration/personal-details.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/registration/personal-details.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>next</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/registration/cultural-details.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/registration/cultural-details.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>previous</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/registration/personal-details.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>next</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/registration/profile-details.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/registration/profile-details.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>previous</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/registration/cultural-details.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>next</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/registration/preview.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/registration/preview.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>previous</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/registration/profile-details.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/registration-complete.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

    <flow-return id="cancel">
        <from-outcome>cancel</from-outcome>
    </flow-return>

    <finalizer>#{registrationBean.finalizeFlow}</finalizer>
</flow-definition>
```

When I move through the Faces Flow, there are no problems in the actual flow pages, but the template is outputting a strange error:

```
Unable to find matching navigation case from view ID '/registration/personal-details.xhtml' for outcome 'registration'
```

Where `/registration/personal-details.xhtml` is the current file name and `registration` is the name of the current Flow Scope.

The rendered link I have in my menu is also rendered as:

```
Sign Up
```

Outside the flow, or:

```
Sign Up: This link is disabled because a navigation case could not be matched.
```

Inside the flow.

At the same time, the Glassfish log is giving me this:

```
Warning:   JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, /registration/registration.xhtml.
```

This `registration.xhtml` doesn't exist, but I thought I could override the default file name by changing the `<start-node>` in the config.

Is there a way I can keep my file structure with the non-default value and get this working? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the first view must be `registration.xhtml` (or `<FLOW_NAME>.xhtml` in general), so I can get rid of the error message, and technically this "answers" my question, but I would prefer to be able to name my views as I see fit, and not have to default if possible, so I'll hold out for a while on selecting an answer in case anybody has any better input on this matter.

Comment: It seems that the only way I can find is to work with the default naming convention. Bit ugly, but until there is a better offer, this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the start page (or use any arbitrary faces page in any directory) using the FlowBuilder inside a @Producer method instead of XML configuration.

See: https://blog.oio.de/2014/02/12/a-comprehensive-example-of-jsf-faces-flow/

This would require switching from face-config.xml to code based configuration... Faces/directory based configuration is not very flexible and requires sticking to the standard convention.